# Spring Security for Active Directory searches by 'userPrincipalName' -- is there a way to change this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, active-directory

I'm still learning LDAP / Active Directory so correct me if my terminology is wrong at all :)

In our Java Web Application, I'm trying to secure it with Spring Security LDAP. I managed to get Spring Security working with in-memory authentication but we need to tie it to our AD server.

I'm going to mask our actual domain with **com.test**

Here is the error I receive when I try to login from my application

> 13:39:55,701 ERROR ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider:133 -
>   Failed to locate directory entry for authenticated user: johnsmit
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D:
>   NameErr: DSID-0310020A, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match
>   of:   'CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=com'

I am using class based configuration with Spring
Here is my SecurityConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
          provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("ad.test.com", "ldap://servername.ad.test.com:389/cn=Users,dc=ad,dc=test,dc=com");

        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);


        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }
}
```

So here is the issue (at least I think)...
In our AD server we have our 
**cn**,**name**,**sAMAccountName** and **uid** as our username that we login with, *johnsmit* in my example above.

Our userPrincipalName (in our AD server) is our email address so *john.smith@test.com*.

I was looking at the [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html) class and it says it uses the userPrincipalName. Looking in the code [here on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L278) it shows that it is using userPrincipalName. I checked the newer versions of Spring Security which is not General Availability yet, but it was the same thing.

There *must* be someway that I can search AD with the username "johnsmit" instead of "john.smith@test.com"...

If the searchFilter was
`String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))";` that would be the ideal situation but I don't know if that is possible to override anywhere and I can't find any documentation?

Answer (score 4):

As I found this eminently helpful in solving my own problem, I'd just like to add that the changes suggested by [@JanTheGun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819165/1138932) appear to have been folded into Spring Security 5.0.8.RELEASE / Spring Boot 2.0.5

The JavaDoc for `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setSearchFilter(String)` reads:

> The LDAP filter string to search for the user being authenticated. Occurrences of `{0}` are replaced with the `username@domain`. Occurrences of `{1}` are replaced with the username only.
>
> Defaults to: `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})))`

Therefore, in Spring Security 5.0.8.RELEASE, it's possible to use the suggested search-filter change *without* having to replicate any of the Spring Security classes!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I will answer my own question with this Jira ticket

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1915

Looks like it simply hasn't been merged in. The patch in this ticket would be the answer I need though.

Answer (score 1):

Three years later I am also struggling with that problem. As there is the recommendation to change the userPrincipalName to the mail address for Office365 (see [Office 365 – Why Your UPN Should Match Your Primary SMTP Address](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/07/office-365-why-your-upn-should-match-your-primary-smtp-address/)) I thought others might also have the problem - so here is my fix.

There is a discussion on github that is talking about the issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2448

The answer of user gkibilov solved my problem. The idea is to change the "searchForUser" method in the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class in order to not only pass the bindprincipal (=USERNAME@DOMAIN) but also the username.

Afterwards the following searchFilter can be used to look for the sAMAccountName instead of the userPrincipalName:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={1}))"
```

**Here are the single steps that I did:**

1. Copy the source of the *ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException* class
   to a new class and rename it (ie     "*MyActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException*"): [SourceLink](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException.java)
2. Copy the source of the *ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider*
   class to a new class and rename it (ie
   "*MyActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider*"): [SourceLink](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java)
3. Exchange the *ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException* class in *MyActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider* with the new exception class (*MyActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException*)
4. Change the method in *MyActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException* class to also pass the username:

   ```
   private DirContextOperations searchForUser(DirContext context, String username)
       throws NamingException {
        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String bindPrincipal = createBindPrincipal(username);
        String searchRoot = rootDn != null ? rootDn
                : searchRootFromPrincipal(bindPrincipal);

        try {
            return SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(context,
               searchControls, searchRoot, searchFilter,
               new Object[] { bindPrincipal, username});
        }
        ...
   }
   ```
5. Change the searchFilter to look for the sAMAccountName attribute. In your case the bean should look like this:

   ```
   @Bean
   public MyActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
       provider = new MyActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("ad.test.com", "ldap://servername.ad.test.com:389/cn=Users,dc=ad,dc=test,dc=com");
       provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={1}))");
       provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
       return provider;
   }
   ```

I have to admit that it is not the nicest solution to copy a class but as the original class is "final" I couldn't find a better way to fix this problem.